# Do companions level up over time? Does it matter what equipment they carry around?

Tags: starfield

My first companion on *Starfield* is "Sarah Morgan".

Does she level up over time when she accompanies me on missions?

Does it matter what kind of weapons, suits, or helmets I give her to add to her inventory?
Does she use such items at all?

Is a "human" companion acting the same way as, for example, Vasco (the robot)?
(Protecting me? Leveling up? Carrying weight?)

Comment: This is fairly broad (you are asking multiple questions in one post).  You may want to break this down into a post per question.

Comment: Is it really better to ask 5 to 7 separate questions about the same specific "Companion"? As the given answer shows it is quiet easy to write a very useful answer.

Comment: @PeterCo I believe there are two or three questions in your post. I'd ask this part in a separate question: "Does it matter what kind of weapons, suits, or helmets I give her to add to her inventory?" The other two questions could be combined or phrased to be more focused.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<sub>Technically everyone's first companion is Vasco, but this is during what some consider the "tutorial" part of the game.</sub>

No, companions do not level up. They have different stats from each other (some specialize in marksmanship, others specialize in assisting on your ship, etc.), but these are also static throughout the game.

> #### Will our companions be able to level up their perks?
>
> **Emil**: They don't level up, but they come at different ranks, depending on the companion. Well, we call them Skills in Starfield. And they do stack with yours, where relevant.
> Some are there for flavor, to highlight the companions' background and interests. But you'll really feel the benefit of the ship- and combat-related ones. Getting a boost to your shields, or seeing your companion laying fown fire from a weapon they're proficient in, are pretty sweet moments.

<sub>Source: Design Director Emil Pagliarulo on a Q&A from Discord, the transcript for which can be found here: https://www.reddit.com/r/Starfield/comments/15swuqp/discord_server_qa_full_transcript/</sub>

To change their gear or weapons, you can trade with them, and then select which gear or weapons they have equipped from their inventory. One of Sarah Morgan's skills is Lasers (rank 3), so you will definitely want to make sure you keep her armed with a laser-based weapon rather than a ballistics weapon or other kind.

As for their behavior, all companions will join you in a fight if they are with you when you engage.

Comment: I noticed that when you add a companion, their skills show with icons at upper right. I also noticed these skills did not show up for Sarah Morgan and Barret until *after* they were removed from my party and then added back. I think this is because they are sort of non-optional when they get added the first time which bypasses the GUI display. I had no idea Sarah was level 3 lasers until the "mandatory" portion of that early quest was done. I think this information is accessible in the ship menu even if they are not assigned to a ship.

Comment: Note they need at least one round of ammo (they don't use it up) to use a weapon you give them, and the spacesuit/armor you manually have them equip may not be visible when they are in non-space environments. So long as they have it marked equipped, they get the benefit.